# Claraification on asp.net mvc version numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently I'm totally struggeling with `asp.net mvc` version numbers and assembly version numbers. The chaos is compleet with the new `Asp.Net Core`.

When I'm creating a new `ASP.Net MVC` website using `Visual Studio 2015` and `.Net Framework 4.5.1`, it adds assemblies with the Version number `5.2.3`. Does this mean `MVC Version 5` or `MVC Version 6`? And is this (one of them) the same code base as `ASP.NET Core 1.0` uses?

And how to bring `asp.net 4.6` with this together, or do I have to differentiate between `aspnet` and `asp.net mvc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET 4.6 are **two totally different things**, ASP.NET Core is the new version of ASP.NET with the open source flag all over it, ASP.NET 4.6 is more mature and stable than ASP.NET Core, [Scott made a great post about it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)

ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC are also not the same think because ASP.NET Mvc implements the Model View Controller pattern and the releases are separated from ASP.NET itself.

To explain it better **you can look at ASP.NET as a web platform**. It provides a layer that sits on top of IIS this allow you to create web applications. **ASP.NET MVC is a framework that sits on top of ASP.NET** and uses APIs provided by ASP.NET.

For example ASP.NET Web Forms is another framework that sits on top of ASP.NET as ASP.NET Web API and WCF.

Comment: Thank you :) What are the differences between `asp.net 4.6` and `asp.net mvc 5.2.3`? Does `mvc 5` bases on `asp.net 4.6` than?

Comment: take a look at my new edit to see if you understand it better.

Comment: @BendEg to answer your question, yes MVC 5 sits on ASP.NET 4.6. MVC 6 will be using ASP.NET 5 (vNext) or ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @DiogoCunha, thank you, that makes sense :) So using `asp.net mvc 5.2.3` with the recommended `asp.net` platform will be the best solution for the moment. Later I can upgrade to use `asp.net core 1.0` with the pending `asp.net mvc` on top of it.

Comment: @BendEg sure, you can but like Scott says in the post  ASP.NET 4.6 is the more mature platform. It's battle-tested and released but ASP.NET Core release includes a MVC and Web Api

Comment: @DPac Actually, MVC 6 is not really a thing anymore with the new naming scheme.  As I understand it, the MVC and WebAPI frameworks are no longer going to be separate releases, but part of ASP.Net Core itself.